# How to make buttons blinking with specific time?

Tags: javascript

i would like to ask all , i am face with issue that i want to blink three html links when user clicks on the button with specific time

```
<a id="tip1">blink1</a> 
<a id="tip2">blink2</a> 
<a id="tip3">blink3</a>
<input type="button" value="CLICK ME" id="btn" />
 $("#btn").click(function () {
doBlink(900);
});
function doBlink(900)
{
set blink for $("#tip1") is 300, after finishing for blinking one, we will call for blink2..etc..
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @MikeCheel A GIF would be severe overkill when this can easily be done with JS...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bic742/7C9Jm/) that will do this:

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    doBlink(900);
});

function doBlink(value) {
    var time = value/3;
    blink(1, time);
}

function blink(id, time) {
    var counter = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
       $("#tip" + id).toggleClass('blinked');
       counter += 50;
       if (counter >= time && id < 4) {
           clearInterval(interval);
           id++;
           blink(id, time);
       }
    }, 100);
}
```